# Parented hitboxes with attributes in .FBX

Tags: maya, fbx, asset-management

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogm5t.png)'s a visual description.

In Maya, I want to:

- have boxes parented to my model
- have these boxs scale/translate/rotate with respect to each limb.
- have them to carry attribute data that describes if they enabled, what state they are in, and a flag that states they are geometry that should not be drawn.
- have all of the hitbox data defined in the FBX.

I want to store attribute data that changes while the animation plays, e.g. frames 1-8 have an attribute that states that the hitbox is "HITTABLE", and frames 9-19 have the attribute state "INVULNERABLE".

I want to keep all of the hitbox data: their position, scale, rotations, and their states within the FBX file so that no adjustments need to be made in code for them, and that they can be tweaked when the animation is tweaked.

Comment: @Anko/Tofu_Craving_Redish_BlueDragon - Really appreciate that you guys made my question way spiffier!  Glad you felt the question was informative enough to keep around.